# Causal Mediation Analysis with Confounding by Alternative Mechanism returning NA ACME and ADE Estimates

Tags: mediation

I am pretty new to mediation analyses and am attempting to troubleshoot some results I am getting from a causal mediation I am conducting with an alternative mediator. So I am using the multimed function from the mediation package in R.

I believe my code is okay (why I am not posting this to stack overflow) - ie my variables are numerical, they do not have any factor levels on them, no missing data, ect.

When I run my model, though I am getting NA for my ACME and ADE fro both the estimates under the homogenous interaction assumption and for the sensitivity analysis. All that is being returned is my estimated Total Effect.

I wanted to check on this forum to see what might cause that. Is there some mathematical reason why this model isn't estimating the AMCE and ADE's, could it be a model misspecification, something like too little variation in my DV, model not converging, or is this really just a coding issue?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please include your code and output. That will really help us figure out what's going on, even if you don't think you've made a mistake.

Comment: Last I checked, mediation:: can be pretty picky with numerical input; I'd check to confirm that the variables are doubles (not integers, which would still be numeric)